# How much energy does proton - carbon 12 fusion produce?

Tags: stars, fusion, stellar-physics

Page 25 of [this document](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~jlc/ay219_spring2010/nuclear_reactions_18april2010.pdf) from the California Institute of Technology says that proton-carbon 12 fusion releases 7.54 MeV, while [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle#Cold_CNO_cycles) says it releases 1.95 MeV. Which one is correct?

Comment: Looks like a copy-n-paste error in the PDF. Note that the energy is the same as for the C-13 to N-14 line.

Comment: OK, so what does a third (and fourth) source say?  It's not all that hard to figure out who's in error.

Answer (score 3):

OK, you are referring to the fusion reaction

$^{12}$C + $^{1}$H $\rightarrow$ $^{13}$N + $\gamma$.

Let's neglect the $\gamma$ and insert the [atomic masses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_mass)

$12\cdot u + 1.00782503223\cdot u = 13.005738609\cdot u + x$,

where $x$ is an *upper* boundary for the released energy (since we neglected the $\gamma$). The data for the atomic masses is from the [NIST website](http://www.nist.gov/pml/data/comp.cfm) and from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_nitrogen).

Solving that equation yields

$x=0.00208642323\cdot u$

which corresponds to ($1\cdot u$ corresponds approximately to $931.5$ MeV)

$x\approx 1.94 $ MeV.

Therefore, the wikipedia value seems to be right.